# Issue to deploy webservice in weblogic 12.1.3 C?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy a webservice application in to weblogic 12.1.3 server. In order to deploy the application

1. Log in to oracle weblogic 12.1.3 console.
2. Click deployment
3. Browser the application
4. Select the path and server where i want to deploy the application
5. Activate change and start all the service.

Once i finish the above step i check the weblogic console it said the Web Application is active. But when click the **+** it's displayed  webservie is none.

I can't see any error is weblogic logs. I have deployed the same application in weblogic 9.2. I can access the service with out any issue. Different between this two application is they application which was deployed in weblogic 12.1.3 is running java 7 and other one is running java 1.5.

Please advice me

Answer (score -2):

Weblogic often mask or don't show error. For example, you will never saw error in PostConstruct method of Singleton if it has not bean management transaction setted. The first, try to redirect stdout and stderr into log file. For this purpose go to the console of wls 12c, then \your domain\Environment\Servers\your server\Logging tab\Advanced. In most of all cases there are no difference between running code, which was compiling for java 5, under jvm 5 or 7.

Comment: your answer doesn't match from any way the purposed question

Comment: Can you describe your opinion? I have such kind of trouble and have solved it with this method.